# How to converting a Java List in a Java Map when serializing to JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, dictionary, jackson

I have a List with *Person*'s in Java and each person has an id:

```
class Person{
  public int id;
  public String name;
}
```

Now I like to serialize this list in a JSON like that:

```
{
  "1":{
    "name": "tom"
  },{
  "2":{
    "name": "bob"
  }
}
```

Is there any anotation for the class which contains the list, to specify the JSON structure?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do it. if you serialize the list it will looks like :

Comment: @Jaroslaw.zawila I hoped in Jackson there is an annotation like XmlJavaTypeAdapter in jaxb

Comment: You can define custom serializer (and deserializer if you need it back) using @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=MySerializer.class); (contentUsing because it's to be used for List values, not List itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the above strictly using the Person class, you need

1. To use a map
2. Another class to represent the `name`

> ```
> class PersonName{
>   String name;
> }
>
> Map<int, String> map = new HashMap<int, String>();
>
> map.put(person.getId(), personName);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I want to keep the List I added a method "getPersonsAsMap()" which converts the list to a map. I annotated this method with "JsonProperty" and the method to getting the list with "JsonIgnore". Finally only the map would be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that if you always want Persons to be serialized this way, you can add custom serializer for type, and register that. There are multiple ways to do this: either use `SimpleModule` to register it, or use `@JsonSerialize(using=PersonSerializer.class)` on `Person` class (this annotation can also be used on properties; property one will have precedence if both defined).